# Ajax call returning blank error in Phonegap application

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova

I am trying to call the jquery ajax function in a phonegap application.  Here is my code:

```
            var loginData = {
            email : $('#email').val(),
            password : $('#password').val()
            };

           $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:8081/api/login',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.accessToken);
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                    alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
                },
                data: loginData
            });
```

My config.xml inside my www folder looks has this in it:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

The Status returned is "error" and the error thrown is empty.  What can I try to get this to work?

I have added CORS support to my node.js server and the Ajax works with my browser but not in my Phonegap application.  I still get a status of O.

Comment: Is the code valid JSON? What is triggering the Ajax call?

Comment: I added the JSON i was sending...

Comment: Is the JSON coming back valid? If you change the content type to text, does it work?

Comment: No, I still get an error of unknown type with dataType as 'text'.

Comment: I figured out my problem, I think.  I'm trying a cross-server post which I can't do...

Comment: actually didn't fully solve my problem yet.  the post works in firefox but not in my phonegap application.